# Is it possible to use one replace function to replace multiple strings in one field?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

In my report I need to use the built-in replace function to replace for example "a" with "b" and "c" with "d".

When I just use 2 functions like this:
Replace(Fields!field1.Value, "a", "b") & Replace(Fields!field1.Value, "c", "d")
I get the text from the field twice in my report.

Is it possible to do this? Maybe nest two replace functions? I'm new to reporting services so I could be missing a very obvious solution to this.

Note: I would write my own code to do this but the report is for Microsofts Dynamics CRM 2011 which doesn't allow custom code in a report.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to nest the function's

For example to replace 1 with a and 0 with b you can write the expression below

**=Replace(Replace(Fields!field1.Value,"1","a"),"0","b")**

Comment: Maybe you could use the built-in System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace function, but I am not too familiar with regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

This can be a bit tricky (at first) when you have a string that has part of it repeated in the string after it that you also want to replace.
To give you an example: If you use the nested function from niktrs to replace "Test" with "Test A" and "Test B" with "Test C" it returns "Test A" and "Test A B".
In this example you need to adjust the expression to:

**=Replace(Replace(Fields!Field1.Value,"Test","Test A"),"Test A B","Test C")**

With 2 or more of these type of strings you need to work your way (down the tablix) to the last value that needs replacing, which could leave you with a relatively lengthy expression, unfortunately. It's probably better to alter the query for the dataset you're working with.