# Trying to replace a certain character in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to replace a the charater `0` when pulling through a report. I have entered the expression below and when I run my report I get a `#Error` any hints on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

`=IIf(Fields!HomeAddress2.Value & " " & Fields!HomeAddress3.Value & " " &Fields!HomeAddress4.Value  = 0, Fields!HomeAddress2.Value & " " & Fields!HomeAddress3.Value & " " &Fields!HomeAddress4.Value, "")`

Comment: Try putting quotes around the 0 so it is seen as a character and not an integer.

Comment: Thanks for that, it does work. The only thing it blanks the whole field. Will have to see if I can find something else as I've tried `<` and `>` as well.

Comment: I'm not exactly clear on what you are trying to accomplish with that expression. Currently, it looks like you will always evaluate to the false condition since you are explicitly adding spaces in the string so it will never end up equal to "0". Also, there is a replace function in SSRS expressions. And your false condition is blank, which explains what you are seeing.

Comment: Ah ok, so what would be the syntax for a replace function?

Comment: Replace - 
Returns a string in which a specified substring has been replaced with another substring a specified number of times.
=Replace(Fields!Description.Value,"tube","headlight")
http://www.venkateswarlu.co.in/MSBI/ssrs/ssrs_common_functions__text.aspx

Comment: Ok thanks, just like the excel function then. I will give this a try and will let you know.

Comment: Thanks for this, I have done that change and it works.

Comment: @mmarie if I had multipul things to replace could I do something like `=Replace(Fields!Description.value, "tube" & "Underground", "Hello")`

Comment: @mmarie can this also be used if a value that is returned is a positive number to change it into just `+` and when it is a negative value into just `-`?

Comment: You can have multiple replaces in an expression.  This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608128/is-it-possible-to-use-one-replace-function-to-replace-multiple-strings-in-one-fi

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it similar to NULL?
Maybe you can try `ISNULL( <your expression>, " ")`

Comment: Could this cover multipul characters?

Comment: you can use ISNULL(HomeAddress2,' ')+' '+ISNULL(HomeAddress3,' ')+'  '+ISNULL(HomeAddress4,'  ') AS Addr in the SQL query itself

Comment: Ah, I don't have access to the actual SQL query only the ability to create or edit expressions.