# SSRS #Error in combination with IIF and Cdbl

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

hope someone more experienced can give me answer/solution to my problem.
In a database I have two columns, one to control do we show data and the data to be shown is in the second column.
I have data and expression as below:

```
ShowPriceOnMatrix | RSP
-------------------------------
0                 | 1.48
1                 | 10.26 euro    -> This one fails with #Error
1                 | 4.59
0                 | 7.12


=IIF(Fields!ShowPriceOnMatrix.Value = 1, CDbl(Fields!RSP.Value), "")
```

This expression sometimes gives me #Error.
The problem is that the RSP field was defined as **nvarchar** and I cant change it now so I'm trying to convert to number and show as. Some users when input price on the filed they also type a text ex. "12.45 euro" or similar. When the expression hits a value with text the whole IIF fails with an #Error even if the first column is stated not to show the price.

The problem with IIF is that it is not skipping the second parameter if the first one evaluates to false - and therefore produces #Error in my case.

I've tried to use

```
IsNumeric(Cdbl(Fields!RSP.Value))
```

and

```
IsError(Cdbl(Fields!RSP.Value))
```

but both of them give an #Error also. From SSRS explanation for those functions, they should return a Boolean value but somehow I'm getting #Error :)

Comment: Have you tried to strip out anything after the last digit to remove stuff like euro or pounds or whatever. After that you should be left with only numeric values so you should be able to continue without the #Error popping up.

Comment: I can't predict if the user will type an integer (and how many digits) and/or decimal number and how many decimal digits. Is there another function that can help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just convert the field to numeric using

```
VAL(Fields!RSP.Value)
```

Also, you might want to consider using SWITCH instead of IIF. SWITCH stops at the first expression which evaluates to True, whereas IIF will evaluate all expressions regardless of if they will be used or not.

In your case, with a single IIF, SWITCH is not relevant but in cases where nested IIFs are used or situations where you may get a divide by zero error, SWITCH is often easier to read/debug. So something like this where we have a hypothetical situation that we want to test for divide by zero and return zero or if the thing we are dividing by is negative we want to return -1, otherwise do the calc...

```
=IIF(Fields!MyDivisor.Value = 0, 0, IIF(Fields!MyDivisor.Value <0, -1,  Fields!MyNumber.Value/ Fields!MyDivisor.Value))
```

would become

```
=SWITCH (
    Fields!MyDivisor.Value =0, 0,
    Fields!MyDivisor.Value <0, -1,
    True, Fields!MyNumber.Value/ Fields!MyDivisor.Value
    )
```

each expression/result pair is evaluated in order until it hits the first True expression, so if MyDivisor was zero it would return 0 and stop, if it was negative, it would return -1 and stop. The final `True` acts like an else (as True always returns True ! ) so it would only do the calculation if all other expressions returned false.

Comment: Thanks Alan, VAL() worked to convert it to a numeric value and I'll mark this as an answer as it solved my issue. I would also appreciate if you give me an example of SWITCH here for future use :)

Comment: It's probably not relevant in your case you would usually use it in place of nested IIFs. Often its used to avoid divide by zero where you test for zeros in your first expression. I'll update the answer with ans example anyway.

Comment: Nice, good to know that `VAL()` function is really usefull. I had never heard of this function before.

Comment: It is, SSRS uses (a subset I think) of vb.Net and a lot of old school vb functions are available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this expression to extract your numeric values:

```
=System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(Fields!RSP.Value, "[^0-9,]", "")
```

But you have to take care of the `.` in `1.48`. With `,` and the language `DE` it worked for me. With `.` it would be:

```
=System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(Fields!RSP.Value, "[^0-9.]", "")
```

Comment: Regex didn't work at my end, was not recognised after System.Text

Comment: Hmm I thought this would also exist in `ssrs-2008`. Well then you can use this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608128/is-it-possible-to-use-one-replace-function-to-replace-multiple-strings-in-one-fi

Comment: wow, with that approach I would have to nest as many functions as characters I need to replace. Ex. 26 nested Replace() only to replace the small case letters, another 26 to replace the Uppercase letters + all the special characters and symbols etc.